# Question about T-cyclic space of a vector $v$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ a vector space and $v \in V$ and $T \in End_k(V)$ . Show that if there exists $p \in K[x]-\{0\}$ such that $v \in V_p$ (where $V_p$ is the kernel of $p$), then $\dim (C_T(v))$ (the dimension of the T-cyclic space of $v$) is finite and $m_v$ divides $p$.

I know that if $v \in V_p = \{u \in V: p(T)(u) = 0\}$ so $p(T)(v) = 0$ and $C_T(v) = \{g(T)(v) | g(x) \in K[x]\}$ and another definition is that $C_T(v) = span\{v, T(v), T^2(v), \ldots, T^k(v), \ldots \}$, but I don't know how to use this to prove the question.

Comment: If $p(x) = a_nx^n+\cdots +a_1x+a_0$ with $a_n\neq 0$, then $p(T)(v)=0$  means that $a_nT^n(v) = -(a_0v + \cdots + a_{n_1}T^{n-1}(v))$, so $T^n(v)$ is a linear combination of the previous vectors. Show that $T^{n+k}(v)$ is a linear combination of $v,T(v),\ldots,T^{n-1}(v)$ for all $k\geq 0$.